# How do I resolve this error in React Native

Tags: react-native

nvariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Comment: If that is the only error message in the metro console, clearing watchman and restarting the bundler may be the solution. In many cases, something else broke the bundler which triggered this error. For instance, I currently have this error `Error: [mobx-state-tree] expected mobx-state-tree type as argument 1, got undefined instead` which precedes the `Invariant Violation` error. Make sure to resolve any preceding errors first.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: [Same issue #26687](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687#issuecomment-537504575)

Basically, you just need to run:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all 
$ react-native start --reset-cache
```